# Open a file, read content, make content into a list using regex, then print list in python

Tags: python, regex

I am using "import re and sys"

On the terminal, when I type "1.py a.txt"
I want it to read "a.txt", which has these content:

```
17:18:42.525964 IP 66.185.85.146.80 > 192.168.0.15.34436: Flags [.], seq 1:1449, ack 2555, win 1320, options [nop,nop,TS val 3551057710 ecr 43002332], length 1448
17:18:42.526623 IP 66.185.85.146.80 > 192.168.0.15.34436: Flags [.], seq 1449:2897, ack 2555, win 1320, options [nop,nop,TS val 3551057710 ecr 43002332], length 1448
17:18:42.526900 IP 192.168.0.15.34436 > 66.185.85.146.80: Flags [.], ack 2897, win 1444, options [nop,nop,TS val 43002448 ecr 3551057710], length 0
17:18:42.527694 IP 66.185.85.146.80 > 192.168.0.15.34436: Flags [.], seq 2897:14481, ack 2555, win 1320, options [nop,nop,TS val 3551057710 ecr 43002332], length 11584
17:18:42.527716 IP 192.168.0.15.34436 > 66.185.85.146.80: Flags [.], ack 14481, win 1444, options [nop,nop,TS val 43002448 ecr 3551057710], length 0
17:18:42.528794 IP 66.185.85.146.80 > 192.168.0.15.34436: Flags [.], seq 14481:23169, ack 2555, win 1320, options [nop,nop,TS val 3551057710 ecr 43002332], length 8688
17:18:42.528813 IP 192.168.0.15.34436 > 66.185.85.146.80: Flags [.], ack 23169, win 1444, options [nop,nop,TS val 43002448 ecr 3551057710], length 0
17:18:42.545191 IP 192.168.0.15.60030 > 52.2.63.29.80: Flags [.], seq 4113773418:4113774866, ack 850072640, win 270, options [nop,nop,TS val 43002452 ecr 9849626], length 1448
```

then use regex, to remove everything but the ip addresses and the length(total), and print it out as:

```
source: 66.185.85.146 dest: 192.168.0.15 total:1448
source: 66.185.85.146 dest: 192.168.0.15 total:1448
source: 192.168.0.15 dest: 66.185.85.146 total:0
```

but if there are duplicates, then it will read as follows, where it will add the total amounts of the duplicates:

```
source: 66.185.85.146 dest: 192.168.0.15 total:2896
source: 192.168.0.15 dest: 66.185.85.146 total:0
```

Furthermore, if i type "-s" in the terminal like so:

```
"1.py -s a.txt"
```

or

```
"1.py a.txt -s 192.168.0.15"
```

it should sort, for the first -s, it will sort and print the content, and if -s ip, then sort the ips.

currently this is what I have for each item, I want to know how to use them all together.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import sys

file = sys.argv[1]
a = open(file, "r")

for line in a:
   line = line.rstrip()
   c = re.findall(r'^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$',line) #Yes I know its not the best regex for this, but I am testing it out for now
   d = re.findall(r'\b(\d+)$\b',line)

   if len(c) > 0 and len(d) > 0:
      print("source:", c[0],"\t","dest:",c[1],"\t", "total:",d[0])
```

That is what I have so far, I do not know how to use the "-s" or how to sort, as well as how to remove the duplicates, and add the totals when duplicates are removed.

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

To read the `-s` you probably want a library to parse the arguments, like the standard [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). It allows you to specify which arguments your script requires, and their descriptions, and it parses them and ensure their format.

To sort a list there's the `sorted(my_list)` function.

Finally, to ensure there are no duplicates you can use a `set`. This loses the list ordering, but since you are sorting it later it shouldn't be a problem.

Alternatively, there's the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) collection made specifically to add grouped values and sort them.

```
from collections import Counter

results = Counter()

for line in a:
    line = line.rstrip()
    c = re.findall(r'^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$',line) #Yes I know its not the best regex for this, but I am testing it out for now
    d = re.findall(r'\b(\d+)$\b',line)

    if len(c) > 0 and len(d) > 0:
        source, destination, length = c[0], c[1], d[0]
        results[(source, destination)] += int(length)

# Print the sorted items.
for (source, destination), length in results.most_common():
    print("source:", source, "\t", "dest:", destination, "\t", "total:", length)
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this out

Comment: This won't add up all the lengths.  It will instead add multiple Source/Dest combos with different lengths, and will discard Source/Dest combos with lengths already seen.

Comment: Good catch. Fixing it in a moment.

Comment: I think using `Counter` is a better fit for the job then. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Your assignment line is assigning the wrong values to your variables (or you just like confusing variable names ^_-).  It should be `source, destination, length = c[0], c[1], d[0]`

Comment: Thanks again @Rejected . Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks BoopreH and Rejected!

Comment: results[(source, destination)] += length

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=:'int' and 'str'

@BoopreH

Comment: The regex returns a string, and not a number. You just need to call `int(length)`to convert to a number. I've updated the answer. Sorry for the basic mistake.

Comment: Thanks alot! @BoppreH, now to make that argparse work X_X

Answer (score 2):

what you need is `ArgumentParser` for your `-s` parameter, so something like:

```
import argparse
...
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--sort', action='append',
                    help='sort specific IP')
    parser.add_argument('-s2', '--sortall', action='store_true',
                    help='sort all the IPs')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.sortall:
        # store all Ips

    for ip in args.sort:
        # store by ip
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

now you can use the script like:

```
1.py a.txt -s 192.168.0.15
```

or

```
1.py a.txt -s2
```

apart from that, on how to put all together, looks like a homework, so you should read more about python to figure it out.

Comment: I get indentation error at "for ip in args.sort:"

@eLRuLL

Answer (score 1):

`ArgumentParser` to be added- By the way below code works fine for input file path-

```
import re
from  collections import defaultdict 

with open(r"C:\ips.txt",'rb') as ip_file:
    txt = ip_file.read()
    ip=re.findall(r'[0-9.]+[\s]+[>][\s0-9.]+',txt)
    ip1 = ['>'.join(re.findall(r'[0-9.]+(?=[.])',i)) for i in ip]
    packs = re.findall(r'(?<=length )[0-9]+',txt)
    data = zip(ip1,packs)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in data:
        d[k].append(v)
    for i,j in d.items():
        source,destination = i.split('>')[0],i.split('>')[1]
        print "source: {0} destination: {1} total: {2}".format(source,destination,sum(map(int,j)))
```

It prints-

```
source: 192.168.0.15 destination: 66.185.85.146 total: 0
source: 66.185.85.146 destination: 192.168.0.15 total: 23168
source: 192.168.0.15 destination: 52.2.63.29 total: 1448
```

Comment: I tried it with the no ports, as you have it but i get an error, "IndexError: list index out of range" @SIslam